# Finding a unique value from 2 columns and then a ratio of those values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the columns id, player1, and player2. The ID's for a player can be in either of the two columns. I need to find all the unique ID's in column player1 and column player2 combined. Then I need to also find the amount of times each player appears in each column. Finally I want to order it by the ratio of column player1 / column player2.

For instance, I have the following values in the table.

1 103 101

2 103 111

3 232 103

4 223 111

My query would return..

Player 223: 1/0

Player 232: 1/0

Player 103: 2/1

Player 101: 0/1

Player 111: 0/2

I know for the unique IDs I can do something like this

```
select 
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT player1) FROM table) as player1,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT player2) FROM table) as player2
```

and I know for the order I can do something like this

```
ORDER BY player1 / player2 DESC
```

I'm really just having a hard time figuring out what to do once I get the unique ID and then try to get the ratios outputed and sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select player1,player2, CONCAT('Player',IF( (select count(DT.player1) from table as DT where MT.player1 = DT.player1) > 0, player1,player2),':', (select count(DT.player1) from table as DT where MT.player1 = DT.player1), ' / ', (select count(DT.player2) from table as DT where MT.player2 = DT.player2) )  
from table MT
where player1 != player2
group by palyer1,player2
order by (player1/IF(player2 is not null and player2 != 0,player2,1) desc
```

I hope it helps you